# how to create choose file button which choose only pdf files. I want dialogue box to select only pdf file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I know the other options like, to validate when choose file. But I want my dialogue box to not allow the user any other type of file to be selected. This is what I want.

Comment: This is not nearly specific enough. Is this Web Forms? MVC? Nancy? HTML with backing Web API? Are you using a File Upload control? Please tag your question appropriately and show any relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do so by using the attribute accept. Not all browsers do respect that attribute and it could easily be removed via some code inspector. So in either case you need to check the file type on the server side.

```
<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf" />
```